# Using Green's Theorem to compute counterclockwise circulation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

Using Green's Theorem, compute the counterclockwise circulation of $\mathbf F$ around the closed curve C.
$$\mathbf F = (-y - e^y \cos x)\mathbf i + (y - e^y \sin x)\mathbf j$$  C is the right lobe of the lemniscate $r^2 = \cos 2\theta$

I need help starting this question. I already know the formula for Green's Theorem, but how do I set this up so that I can apply that formula.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}=1 \tag 1$$

Now, what is the area enclosed by $C$?

**SPOILER ALERT:** Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal the solution

> Note that we have $$\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}=-e^y\cos(x)$$and $$\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}=-1-e^y\cos(x)$$Thus, taking the difference, we obtain the result in $(1)$.  Then, from Green's Theorem $$\begin{align}\oint_C (F_x\,dx+F_y\,dy)&=\iint_S \left(\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}\right)\,dx\,dy\\\\&=\iint_S (1)\,dx\,dy\\\\&=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\cos(2\theta)}} r\,dr\,d\theta\\\\&=\frac12 \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \cos(2\theta)\,d\theta\\\\&=\frac12\end{align}$$

Comment: Can you explain that sorry I'm still a little lost

Comment: The theorem states the equivalence of the line integral $\oint_C (F_xdx+F_ydy)$ and the integral $\int_S \left(\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}\right)\,dx\,dy$.

Comment: Oh okay I see, how does it equal 1? When I differentiate I get something off.

Comment: What results do you have for each partial?  The difference is $1$.

Comment: With respect to y: -1-e^ycosx + 1-e^ysinx

Comment: With respect to x: e^ysinx + -e^ycosx

Comment: When I subtract them I am not getting 1? I feel like I am making a stupid mistake somewhere LOL

Comment: I've added a Spoiler Alert section that provides the entire solution.  ;-)) ... -Mark

Comment: Beautifully done Dr.MV

Comment: Thank you!  Much appreciative.  -Mark

Answer (score 1):

$A(C)=2\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\sqrt{cos2\theta}}rdrd\theta.$ This integral is easy to calculate

Comment: How did you get those endpoints?

Comment: Using polar coordinates and the fact that the lemniscate is symmetric, maybe if you draw it then it will become clearer. Actually the area of the interior of this curve is well known so the result of the integral should be 1/2.

Comment: Where did the 2 come from?

Comment: $A(C)=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\sqrt{cos2\theta}}rdrd\theta = 2\int_0^{\pi/4}\int_0^{\sqrt{cos2\theta}}rdrd\theta.$ Because the lemniscata has a symmetry with respect to the polar axis.

Comment: Ohhhh okay thanks I see now